# How to pass rows to inner multiple requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a request which obtains rows of questions

```
con.query('select * from questions where `quizId` = ? ', quizId, function(err, rows)
```

then I need to get answers to each question.

```
for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){     
            answer.getAllByQuestionId(rows[i].id, function(err, data){
```

I get answers and questions without any troubles. But I can't add the answers into each question since `rows[i] is undefined`

Here is the whole method:

```
this.getAllByQuizId = function(quizId, callback) {
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.query('select * from questions where `quizId` = ? ', quizId, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) callback(err); 
        completed_requests = 0;

        for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){     
            answer.getAllByQuestionId(rows[i].id, function(err, data, rows){

                    rows[i].answers = data;
                    completed_requests++;

                    if (completed_requests == rows.length - 1) {
                        callback(null, rows);
                    }
                });
            }                               
        });    
    });
}
```

Comment: You can try my below easiest solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, the `i` value in the `for` loop get changed on each iteration whereas the function `answer.getAllByQuestionId` is asynchronous and when the callback is getting called for each iteration the `i` value will be different basically outside of the bounds. And also, the callback of the function `answer.getAllByQuestionId` should have only two arguments and not three as you did.

The easiest fix is, you can use `rows.forEach` instead of `for` loop to handle this as below. Otherwise you can go with promise modules like `async`, `bluebird` etc.

```
this.getAllByQuizId = function(quizId, callback) {
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.query('select * from questions where `quizId` = ? ', quizId, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) callback(err); 
        completed_requests = 0;


            rows.forEach(function(row){ 
               answer.getAllByQuestionId(row.id, function(err, data){

                    row.answers = data;
                    completed_requests++;

                    if (completed_requests == rows.length - 1) {
                        callback(null, rows);
                    }
                });
            });                             
        });    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here:

- You're not returning early in case `err` is set in your `query()` callback. This will cause the rest of the callback to continue to execute on error, so change `if (err) callback(err)` to `if (err) return callback(err)`.
- `rows[i]` will not be what you expect inside your `getAllByQuestionId()` callback because the value of `i` at the time the callback executes will already be equal to `rows.length` instead of the index of the row at the time `getAllByQuestionId()` was called. There are several solutions to this, including:

  - Using `const`/`let` to store the current row, since `const`/`let` variables are scoped to the closest block of any kind (whereas `var` variables are scoped to the closest function block):

    ```
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
      const row = rows[i];
      answer.getAllByQuestionId(row.id, function(err, data, rows) {
        row.answers = data;
        if (++completed_requests === rows.length)
          callback(null, rows);
      });
    }
    ```
  - Using `rows.forEach()` to create a new function scope where the current value is bound properly:

    ```
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      answer.getAllByQuestionId(row.id, function(err, data, rows) {
        // ...
      });
    });
    ```
- Another problem is that you have two variables with the same name (`rows`) and it's not clear which you intended to pass to `callback()`. My guess is that it's `rows` from the `query()`, since you're setting a `.answers` property on its elements. Either way, you will want to change the name of one or both so as not to cause problems.
- Lastly, you're not handling errors that may be passed to your `getAllByQuestionId()` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

Should just use a join if you have a custom SQL query and want to get the answers also.

```
select * from questions q inner join answers a 
on q.questionId = a.questionId where `quizId` = ?
```

But to code it your way with multiple queries cleanly using more recent JavaScript syntax you can use something like this:

```
import promiseAllEnd from 'promiseallend';

dropErrors = async (promises) => promiseAllEnd(promises).filter(x => x!=undefined);

getQuestions = async id => await conPoolQuery('select .. from questions' //

getAnswers = async id => await conPoolQuery('select .. from answers'//

getQuiz = async(id) => await dropErrors(await getQuestions(id).map(getAnswers));
```